# Download movie posters from list of IMDB ids

Tags: python, web-scraping, imdb

I want to download the posters for a list of movies using their IMDB ID. I am using the MovieLens dataset (https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/latest/).

I have found an example online, however, this code downloads all available posters for 1 movie (https://gist.github.com/baderj/7414775)

How do I adapt this to only download the top rated poster (i.e 1 poster) for each of the movies that I have in the list?

I know that I can access the top rated poster by:

```
posters = api_response['posters'][0]
```

And I know that I can download a list of image urls by:

```
for i in test_urls:
    if __name__=="__main__":
        tmdb_posters(i)
```

However, I dont know how to modify the function get_poster_urls to do what I want.

The full script is provided:

```
import os
import requests

CONFIG_PATTERN = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/configuration?api_key= 
IMG_PATTERN = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{imdbid}/images?api_key={key}' 
KEY = '<your_api_key>'

def _get_json(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.json()

def _download_images(urls, path='.'):
"""download all images in list 'urls' to 'path' """

    for nr, url in enumerate(urls):
        r = requests.get(url)
        filetype = r.headers['content-type'].split('/')[-1]
        filename = 'poster_{0}.{1}'.format(nr+1,filetype)
        filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
        with open(filepath,'wb') as w:
            w.write(r.content)
```

I know that I have to modify this section to get a list of urls for the list of IDs that I have.

```
def get_poster_urls(imdbid):
    """ return image urls of posters for IMDB id
        returns all poster images from 'themoviedb.org'. Uses the
        maximum available size. 
        Args:
            imdbid (str): IMDB id of the movie
        Returns:
            list: list of urls to the images
    """
    config = _get_json(CONFIG_PATTERN.format(key=KEY))
    base_url = config['images']['base_url']
    sizes = config['images']['poster_sizes']

    """
        'sizes' should be sorted in ascending order, so
            max_size = sizes[-1]
        should get the largest size as well.        
    """
    def size_str_to_int(x):
        return float("inf") if x == 'original' else int(x[1:])
    max_size = max(sizes, key=size_str_to_int)

    posters = _get_json(IMG_PATTERN.format(key=KEY,imdbid=imdbid))['posters']
    poster_urls = []
    for poster in posters:
        rel_path = poster['file_path']
        url = "{0}{1}{2}".format(base_url, max_size, rel_path)
        poster_urls.append(url) 

    return poster_urls

def tmdb_posters(imdbid, count=None, outpath='.'):    
    urls = get_poster_urls(imdbid)
    if count is not None:
        urls = urls[:count]
    _download_images(urls, outpath)
```

I know that I have to modify this section to take a list instead of a single IMDB ID

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    tmdb_posters('tt0095016')
```